# How to execute batch update in mysql with exception in java?

Tags: java, mysql, transactions

Mysql batch execution may throw a error and rollback the updated rows. But i need to update the batch with that error. ie, if some rows cannot updated then that row update have to ignored and remaining should be updated.

```
String insertTableSQL = "INSERT INTO DBUSER"
                + "(USER_ID, USERNAME) VALUES"
                + "(?,?)";
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(insertTableSQL);
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
            preparedStatement.setInt(1, i);
            preparedStatement.setString(2, "number " + i);
            preparedStatement.addBatch();
        }
        preparedStatement.setInt(1,1);
        preparedStatement.setString(2, "number 1");
        preparedStatement.addBatch();
        preparedStatement.setInt(1,12);
        preparedStatement.setString(2, "number 12");
        // execute insert SQL stetement
        preparedStatement .executeBatch();
```

In the above code, primary key exception occured. But i want to ignore that insertion and continue the further execution. And also i need the failed insertion.

Comment: If my solution not works, please add the error message.

Answer (score 0):

You miss blanks in your statement:

```
String insertTableSQL = "INSERT INTO DBUSER " + "(USER_ID, USERNAME) VALUES " + "(?,?)"; 
                                           ^^                              ^^
```